# laravel chunk (help)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, chunks

when i using postman get the result from chunk,but the result will return empty,how can i solve this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NtL6.png)

here's my code

```
 public function downloadMemberInfo()
{
   error_log('download');
   set_time_limit(240); //testing
   $memberListsArray = array();
    Member::select('vipcode')->where('vipcode','!=','')
        ->chunk(3000,function($members) use($memberListsArray){
        foreach($members as $member){
            $memberListsArray[] = $member;
       }
   });
   return response()->json($memberListsArray);
}
```

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: i wanna get the $memberListsArray of a json

Comment: `set_time_limit(240)` -- If you need this, there's is something really bad going on. Consider things like query limits or even moving the entire script to a background process to prevent unnecessary hacks like these.

Comment: but i remove the '&' of $memberListsArray,it'll return empty value..

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `get` before use `chunk`; [because `chunk` works with collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-chunk). Try with the next code.

```
public function downloadMemberInfo()
{
   error_log('download');
   set_time_limit(240);

   $members = Member::select('vipcode')
      ->where('vipcode', '!=', '')
      ->get()
      ->chunk(3000)
      ->toArray();

   return response()->json($members);
}
```

By the way, I recommend you to use [paginate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination) or some query [limit](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) to avoid performance issues